# How do you knock down cars in Asphalt 8 multiplayer?

Tags: asphalt-8

When playing multiplayer mode I have trouble knocking down cars, the guide says hit from rear or sides, but there seems to be some tricks / conditions to it. I would like to know more of what is required.

Answer (score 3):

In multiplayer, knocking down people is harder than in single player to make it more fair for everyone. You must either (a) ram them at a high rate of speed, but not too fast (you don't want to wreck instead), or (b) grind them against the wall.

Answer (score 1):

The main rule is that you must have a higher speed than the other guy at the moment you hit him. So always use your level 3 nitro boost when knocking down someone.